# Adobe Flex & Air - packaging Air app in native install

Tags: apache-flex, air, packaging, flex3

I have tried the options given on [Adobe Livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html) : adt -package -target native myApp.exe myApp.air, but I keep getting the message "-storetype required". I then try with adt -package -target native -storetype pkcs12 -keystore myCert.pfx myApp.exe myApp.air and get the same message.

I have already created the .air file and the .p12 cert file in flexbuilder, and am just pointing to these in the command prompt in the specified places, but the same problem occurs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.

- Had to insert `<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>` into my app.xml file.
- and also `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0beta2">` into the same xml file.

At lease Adobe Air 2.0 is needed, and ADT needs to be set in the Path. I put a list of the steps I took in getting the Air to Exe on my [**blog**](http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=132) if you interested.

UPDATE: Serje Jespers created a drag-n-drop tool to accomplish this task [**here**](http://www.webkitchen.be/package-assistant-pro/)